# Uploading app on samsung apps

Tags: android, lua, apk, coronasdk, samsung-mobile

I was uploading an app I already have available on Google Play and Amazon AppStore onto Samsung Apps. I am using corona sdk and built for Samsung Apps when I built my final apk. When I upload the apk, it shows an error that says

> This App ID is already being used by another application. Please
>   register an ID by adding a binary from the application.

I am not sure how to fix this so could I please get some help

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Samsung Apps. In my case this issue was solved by changing package name (just to differ from Google Play version) and [app name in manifest](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#label). Not sure what exactly helped but I believe that the reason was in app name. I've left only English name in manifest and made it the same as I put in 'Application Title' field on Samsung Apps during submission. After that I managed to submit my APK.

Answer (score 0):

I can use the same App name in Samsung as I do in Google Play and Amazon.   Just make sure your not using the same name for multiple apps.